# How to print different variables in one plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-analysis

So I have some 2-factor-variables (1,0) and an age variable (numeric), I have done a cluster analysis and I want to plot the different variables in X axis, something like this:

[image: Plot to achieve]

I have tried using ggplot but I just cant get what I am looking for.

So I have the following:

```
visit <- rbinom(20, 1, 0.5)
death <- rbinom(20, 1, 0.5)
gender <- rbinom(20, 1, 0.5)
age <- sample(1:50,20,replace=F)
cluster <- letters[1:5]
df <- data.frame(visit,death,gender,age,cluster)
```

And I want to plot a graph in which in colored line represents the cluster based on the above variables.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Help us help you: Provide a [mcve]. What have you tried so far? Can you [edit] your question to include the output of the R command `dput(df)` (where `df` is the name of your dataframe)? Etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by simply specifying `color` in `aes()` and using `geom_line()`. I initially thought this might be a duplicate, but didn't see any real candidates after a quick search. I will say that I think you would benefit by reading up on some `ggplot2` basics, such as by going through [this guide](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-essentials) (for example).

So, here's how you could produce such a plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = death, y = age, color = cluster)) +
    geom_line()
```

[image]

#### Data

```
set.seed(42) ## Set seed for reproducibility
visit <- rbinom(20, 1, 0.5)
death <- rbinom(20, 1, 0.5)
gender <- rbinom(20, 1, 0.5)
age <- sample(1:50,20,replace=F)
cluster <- letters[1:5]
df <- data.frame(visit,death,gender,age,cluster)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but what I am looking for is to have in the X-axis all the categories like in the gratph in my question and in the Y-axis I want to have a standard deviation for each category.

Comment: I think you need to be a little more specific in your question then @Felipe , specifying which variable in your example dataset should be your x axis, which variable should be your y axis, and which variable should govern the color of the lines drawn